# How to execute a Exception

Tags: java, exception, doubly-linked-list

I don't understand why the catch is not executed.

```
@Override
    public void remove(int value) throws NoSuchElementException {
        ListItem index = head;
        System.out.println("value " + value);
        try {
            if (contains(value) == true) {
                System.out.println("Nö");
                if (head == tail) {
                    tail = null;
                } else if (head.value == value) {
                    head = head.next;
                }
                while ((index.next != null) && (index.next.value != value)) {
                    index = index.next;
                }
                if (index.next == null) {
                    index = null;
                } else if (index.next.value == value) {
                    index.next = index.next.next;
                }
            }
        } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
            System.out.println("HEllo");
            throw new NoSuchElementException("No such Element.");
        }
        // System.out.println("HEllo 2");
    }
```

I thought the Exception is thrown if I do not fulfill my try, I achieve this if I have

`if (contains(value) == true )`

But even if this is false it does not work.

Comment: What does `contains` do? Does it throw the exception?

Comment: The catch is not executed because there is no exception.

Comment: @knittl contains checks if the value already exists in the list

Comment: @luk2302 could you please explain what you mean? I'm a beginner, i'm sorry

Comment: @intact473 You can find my answer below for why there are no Exceptions thrown in your code (assuming contains() does not throw an Exception).

Comment: Hello. Could you please explain what do you mean by "*I thought the Exception is thrown if I do not fulfill my try*" and what makes you think so?

Comment: Off-topic, style comment:  `if (contains(value) == true)` is the same as `if (contains(value))`

Comment: Within your `try` block, there is no explicit statement that throws a `NoSuchElementException`. Since that is the case, if a `NoSuchElementException` is thrown, it must be thrown by a method called within the `try` block. The only method call in the `try` block is `contains (value)`.  We don't see the code for `contains (int)`, but it's fair to conclude that whatever the value of `value` is, it did not cause `contains (int)` to throw a `NoSuchElementException`.

Comment: Also, there's very little point in catching an exception and rethrowing the same exception, which is (almost) what you're doing.  I assume printing "hello" is not a permanent part of your program, since it adds nothing useful for the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Exceptions** in Java are generally `thrown` when there are unexpected behaviors or errors.

In the `try-catch` block you have given, the `catch` block will only execute when the `NoSuchElementException` exception is thrown somewhere within the `try` block.

Hence, just because the code reaches the end of the `try` block without "fulfilling" your `if statement` condition, does not mean the `catch` block you have written will excecute.

You can learn more about **Exceptions** and the `try-catch block` in Java from [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/exceptions-in-java/) and [here](https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_try_catch.asp).

Comment: I assumed by *"I thought the Exception is thrown if I do not fulfill my try"*, you meant *"I thought the Exception is thrown when I fail the if statement condition"*.

Answer (score 1):

As Yağız Can Aslan mention above the catch block will only be trigerred if an `NoSuchElementException` is thrown in your try block

If you want to propagate the exception to the calling method of `remove` you could simply throw the exception yourself if your condition is not fulfilled :

```
@Override
    public void remove(int value) throws NoSuchElementException {
        ListItem index = head;
        System.out.println("value " + value);

            if (contains(value) == true) {
                System.out.println("Nö");
                if (head == tail) {
                    tail = null;
                } else if (head.value == value) {
                    head = head.next;
                }
                while ((index.next != null) && (index.next.value != value)) {
                    index = index.next;
                }
                if (index.next == null) {
                    index = null;
                } else if (index.next.value == value) {
                    index.next = index.next.next;
                }
            } else {
                throw new NoSuchElementException("No such Element.");
            }
        } 
    }
```

The exception will be thrown to the calling method in wich you will have to either make a `try/catch` or re-thrown the exception upward again.